# What is a clean way to modify arguments inside a function in java?

Tags: java, c, parameters

I am interested in doing this C code in Java:

```
// sets n's ith bit from right, i starts from 0
void setBit(int* n, int i){
   *n = *n | (1 << i);
}
```

However, it looks like java can't pass addresses, so what would be some clean approaches?

I thought of two approaches, but I was wondering if there are better ways to do it?

Approach 1: using an array

```
 // sets n[0]'s ith bit from right, i starts from 0
public void setBit(int[] n, int i){
   n[0] = n[0] | (1 << i);
}
```

Approach 2: using a class

```
private class Data{
   int value;
}

// sets d.value's ith bit from right, i starts from 0
public void setBit(Data d, int i){
   d.value = d.value | (1 << i);
}
```

Comment: "I was wondering if there are better ways to do it?" - no.

Comment: thanks Sam, I didn't even notice that feature!

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `BitSet` to set bits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, no better way to do it...

Unless you'd like to do it the traditional Java way, which is

```
d = setBit(d, i);

public int setBit(int d, int i) {
  return d | (1 << i);
}
```

This is all to say in Java that "modifying arguments to a function" is almost *inherently* unclean.  The clean way is to find some alternative to modifying the arguments.

(Sometimes it'll be inevitable, in which case your workarounds are the way to go.   That said, if you want to write a method `modify(myData)`, it's frequently better to add a `modify()` method to `myData`'s class.)

Comment: Looks like we answered *exactly* the same in the same minute. I'm deleting my answer because I prefer your variable naming of 'd' to my 'n'. Goodbye 10 points * sniff *.

Answer (score 3):

How about `int setBit(int n, int i)` which returns a new int with the given bit set?

Alternatively, you could encapsulate this in a class called IntBuilder or something similar:

```
IntBuilder ib = new IntBuilder();
ib.setBit(n);
int i = ib.getInt();
```

This would only really make sense if you had other operations you also want to perform. For just setting a bit, it's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Not a general approach, but in your particular case I would suggest using a mutable integer. The apache-commons-lang3 package contains a nice implementation as `org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableInt`

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html

The .setValue() method will allow you to implement your method in a somewhat C-style way.

*ps: I don't like answers beginning with `Nope, no better way to do it...`. (although sometimes it really is the case...)*